# pandas find constant variables in a huge csv file

Tags: csv, pandas, bigdata

I have a large csv file that I can not load into memory. I need to find which  variables are constant. How can I do that?
I am reading the csv as

```
d = pd.read_csv(load_path, header=None, chunksize=10)
```

Is there an elegant way to solve the problem?

The data contains string and numerical variables

Comment: Are you saying that all row values are the same? You could load the csv in chunks and then compare `value_counts() == len(df)`

Comment: do you mean iterate over the chunks and check everytime?

Comment: Can you define what the problem really is, you can either load in each column for the entire csv and check if all values are the same or load chunks and then compare the uniqueness of the values on each iteration

Comment: It is fine I was just wondering if there was a faster built in method. Take into account that you can not check independently chunk by chunk because the function may be constant on the chunk but not generally.  In the end you will end up with a method similar to the one I have proposed below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current slow solution that does not use pandas

```
    constant_variables = [True for i in range(number_of_columns)]
    with open(load_path) as f:
        line0 = next(f).split(',')
        for num, line in enumerate(f):
            line = line.split(',')
            for i in range(n_col):
                if line[i] != line0[i]:
                    constant_variables[i] = False
            if num % 10000 == 0:
                print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 methods I can think of iterate over each column and check for uniqueness:

```
col_list = pd.read_csv(path, nrows=1).columns
for col in range(len(col_list)):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=col)
    if len(df.drop_duplicates()) == len(df):
        print("all values are constant for: ", df.column[0])
```

or iterate over the csv in chunks and check again the lengths:

```
for df in pd.read_csv(path, chunksize=1000):
    t = dict(zip(df, [len(df[col].value_counts()) for col in df]))
    print(t)
```

The latter will read in chunks and tell you how unique each columns data is, this is just rough code which you can modify for your needs